# Android webview back button

Tags: android, webview, back

In my app when user clicks on a gallery widget i open the image in a webview as it supports zoom functionality.

Now when user clicks back button on webview i want the user to see my application. But it goes directly to home screen.

How should i handle the onBackKeyPressed() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override the Activity's onKeyDown(..) event

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // close image gallery
        return false; // this avoids passing to super
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

*edit: code

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public onBackPressed(){
  if(webView.canGoBack()){
     webView.goBack();
   }else{
   super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide an explanation of what is going on here (from [answer]: "_try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer_") and why this should work, with links to the relevant documentation (if applicable). I would also add a few words about what makes your answer better than the accepted one.